# How does black proceed in the following position?

Tags: analysis

Shown below is a game I have been trying to solve, Black has been better for the whole game but resigns at the end. On checking the analysis stockfish says black is still better

[image: Stockfish Analysis on Lichess]

```
[Event "Hourly Blitz Arena"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/RS8OKA3q"]
[Date "2021.06.09"]
[White "okotieno"]
[Black "Kryptonopolis"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2021.06.09"]
[UTCTime "15:28:08"]
[WhiteElo "2018"]
[BlackElo "2363"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+11"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-10"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "300+0"]
[ECO "B21"]
[Opening "Sicilian Defense: McDonnell Attack"]
[Termination "Normal"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 c5 2. f4 { B21 Sicilian Defense: McDonnell Attack } d5 3. e5?! { (-0.07 → -0.59) Inaccuracy. exd5 was best. } (3. exd5 Nf6 4. Nc3 Nxd5 5. Nxd5 Qxd5 6. Qf3 Qe6+ 7. Qe3 Nc6) 3... Nc6 4. Bb5 Bd7 5. Bxc6 Bxc6 6. d3?! { (-0.62 → -1.17) Inaccuracy. d4 was best. } (6. d4 Nh6 7. Nf3 e6 8. c3 Nf5 9. O-O cxd4 10. cxd4 Bb5) 6... d4 7. Nf3 Nh6 8. Nbd2 e6 9. Ne4 Be7 10. h3?! { (-0.63 → -1.44) Inaccuracy. Qe2 was best. } (10. Qe2) 10... O-O? { (-1.44 → -0.04) Mistake. f5 was best. } (10... f5) 11. g4 Qd5 12. Kf2 c4?! { (-0.76 → 0.01) Inaccuracy. f6 was best. } (12... f6 13. exf6) 13. g5?? { (0.01 → -2.34) Blunder. Re1 was best. } (13. Re1 Rac8) 13... Nf5 14. Rg1 Kh8 15. Qf1 Rac8 16. Bd2?! { (-2.69 → -3.52) Inaccuracy. Qe2 was best. } (16. Qe2 Rfd8 17. h4 cxd3 18. cxd3 Qb5 19. Rd1 Bxe4 20. Qxe4 Rc2+ 21. Rd2 Rdc8 22. h5 g6) 16... cxd3?! { (-3.52 → -2.75) Inaccuracy. b5 was best. } (16... b5 17. Qe2 c3 18. bxc3 dxc3 19. Be3 b4 20. h4 Rfd8 21. h5 a5 22. h6 g6 23. Nf6) 17. cxd3 Bb5 18. Rc1?! { (-2.30 → -3.39) Inaccuracy. a4 was best. } (18. a4 Ba6 19. b4 b6 20. Qe2 Rc2 21. Rgb1 Rfc8 22. Ne1 R2c7 23. a5 Bb7 24. b5 g6) 18... Qxa2 19. Rxc8?! { (-3.01 → -3.78) Inaccuracy. Ng3 was best. } (19. Ng3) 19... Rxc8 20. Bc1? { (-3.78 → -7.51) Mistake. Ng3 was best. } (20. Ng3 Nxg3) 20... Rc2+ 21. Nfd2 Qa6 22. Nf6 Bxd3 23. Qg2 Qc6 24. Qg4 Rxc1 25. Qh5 Bxf6 26. Qxf7 { Black resigns. } 1-0
```

How should black continue to prevent the checkmate on the backrank?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

White threatens 27. Qf8#. Black has several ways to stop the immediate mate, so let's look at them:

1. 26...Qc8? 27. Rxc1 Qg8 (27...Qxc1? 28. Qf8#) 28. Qxg8+ Kxg8 29. gxf6 gives back a decisive amount of material.
2. 26...Qc5? 27. Qe8+ forces mate.
3. 26...Be7 27. Rxc1 Qd7 leaves Black with a still-comfortable material advantage.
4. 26...Rf1+ is a variant of the above idea. After 27. Nxf1 or Rxf1 Black plays 27...Be7 and maintains a still-comfortable material advantage.
5. 26...h6? 27. Qf8+ Kh7 28. g6#
6. 26...h5? 27. Qf8+ Kh7 28. g6+ Kh6 29. Qh8#
7. 26...Nh6 27. gxh6 Bh4+ is the computer's main line. 28. Rg3 (only legal move) Bxg3+ 29. Kxg3 Rg1+ 30. Kh4 Qc8 leaves Black up more than a decisive amount of material.

The last line is admittedly somewhat difficult to spot, but 26...Be7 is still winning.

Comment: Bh4+ is what I was missing after white picks the knight, thanks

Comment: Thoughts on 26. … h5 (instead of h6)? It doesnt look like it falls to the g6 mate im (5), but I could see 27. Qxh5+ being annoying/starting to give up those material advantages

Comment: @D.BenKnoble 26. …h5 would be a blunder because of the same variation provided by Allure 26...h6? 27. Qf8+ Kh7 28. g6+ Kh6 29.Qh8#

Comment: 6. `26...Nh6 27. Qf8+ Ng8` (the declined sacrifice becomes the only blocker that self-pins to stop mate) is mind-bendingly precise but good to study and get comfortable with.

Comment: on the first line, with `Qg8 (forced)` I don't see what's wrong with, e.g. `Qb8`? Why it is forced? I imagine `Qb8` leads to `gxf3 gxf3. Qxf3+ Ng7`, which is the same result in material losses for black.

Comment: @njzk2 I meant Black has to move the queen and cannot play Qxc1. I'll edit.

Comment: @njzk2, `26...Nh6 27. Qf8+ Ng8 28. gxf3` continues with `28... Rxg1` and White can no longer checkmate.

Comment: @Stadem ah, yes, didn't see Rxg1, thanks